# Lost my google chrome bookmarks and extentions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I just lost my Google Chrome bookmarks and extensions after restarting my laptop and it's really annoying.

I didn't find bookmarks.bak in \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default (or anywhere else for that matter)

No, I don't use synchronization. And no, I don't use a bookmark extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You learned a valuable lesson: *always backup!*

If the file you're looking for is not in:

`C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`

Ways you might be able to solve this:

1. Your bookmarks.bak might be hidden, try enabling the item highlighted in the folder options.
2. You could try using undelete, or if you use Windows Restore Point revert to an earlier version.
3. There might be a file that matches the pattern
   `Bookmarks~RF1bc01ae.TMP`

[image]

Comment: It's not hidden and I found no files with the word "book". I'll try to un-delete it if I can.

Comment: I could partially recover two files deleted today it seems. Although I couldn't restore my bookmarks, this is an acceptable answer. Thank you.